# Сохранение/считывание QList в QSettings

Tags: c++, qt

Пытаюсь сохранять список таким образом:

```
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(QList<double>)
QList <double> x_distorsio_coef;


void MainWindow::save_settings()
{
    qRegisterMetaTypeStreamOperators <QList<double>> ("QList<double>");
    settings->setValue("x_distorsio_coef", QVariant::fromValue(x_distorsio_coef));
}

void MainWindow::load_settings()
{
    x_distorsio_coef = settings->value("x_distorsio_coef").value <QList<double>> ();
}
```

Собственно говоря, в ini-файл это всё сохраняется как набор байтов. А вот считывания почему-то не происходит: в load_settings() проверяю размер списка после считывания, он равен нулю. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: QList<double> зарегистирован, когда вы вызвали load_settings? Как я вижу, регистрируется он только в save_settings()